# Poisson Quasi Maximum Likelihood Estimator in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, poisson, mle

I am trying to compute Poisson Quasi Maximum Likelihood Estimator (Poisson-QML or Poisson-PML) in MATLAB on some data about trade.

Is there already a coded function in MATLAB to calculate this estimator, or do I need to code it myself?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just calculating the regular [Poisson distribution maximum likelihood estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Maximum_likelihood), which is rather straightforward? See also [`mle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mle.html). If you're using this to estimate parameters, see [`poissfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/poissfit.html), which is based on MLE.

Comment: Because with that function I can not proceed to calculate Standard Errors. I receive folowing error message:
`Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in robust_se (line 7)
mat1 = inv( zex'*((exp(zex*b1)*ones(1,kexog)).*zex) );

Error in new1 (line 102)
se1 = robust_se(b1, x, zex); `
@horchler